# Remainder for negative fraction division

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What will be the remainder for the following division and what is the generale rule applied to it:
$$ (-25)^{-1}\; mod\; 26  \;$$ ?

Comment: So you have to find a number $a= (-25)^{-1}$ which satisfies $a\times (-25)\equiv 1\pmod{26}$. With some calculation, you can see that $1\times (-25) \equiv 1\pmod{26}$, and so $(-25)^{-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{26}$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, for the equation 
$$ax\equiv 1\pmod n,$$
this can be solved by running extended Euclidean algorithm on the pair $(a, n)$, which gives $x'$ and $y'$ that satisfy
$$\begin{align*}
ax' + ny' &= \gcd(a,n)\\
((-25)\cdot1 +26\cdot 1 &= 1)
\end{align*}$$

If $\gcd (a,n) = 1$, i.e. $a$ and $n$ are coprime, then the $x'$ will satisfy the equation.

Otherwise, if $\gcd(a,n)>1$, then the equation

$$ax + ny = 1$$

has no solution, because the left hand side is divisible by $\gcd (a,n)$ but the right hand side is not.

Answer (score 0):

$$-(m-1)^{-1}\equiv-(-1)^{-1}\equiv -(-1)\equiv 1\pmod m$$